# How would I determine statistical significance on exponential data?

Tags: time-series, statistical-significance, exponential-distribution

I'm trying to determine if there's a statistically significant difference between the O2 permeability into two different materials.

The measurements are percentage of O2 (O2%), measured every 15 seconds. O2% can obviously only go up to 100%, so the data looks like an exponential decay, mirrored about the x-axis (like $-a^{-x} $).

I have three times series in each material, and want to compare each material. I assume I first need to average each time-point in the same material, and maybe get the statistical significance at each time point? But I'm not sure how to go ahead and compare the materials.